# I have to convert a simple program to multiple threads. So that my execution time may reduce

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, multithreading

My task is to make a generic code (using shell prog. Language) which prompts the file name from user then execute the program and break the program in multiple threads (in number of threads a/c to the need).

Comment: Here on Unix.stackexchange.com also unclear as well as it was on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47616908/4023950) which you cross posted. _please don't cross post_, instead you should clarify your question with more details by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/408525/edit), you may need to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The easiest way to find the basics on something is probably to just find some tutorial online, there are likely to be many. After that, if you've tried something, and have questions, the Q&A format of Stackexchange might work better. Anyway, the combination of shell and multithreading seems somewhat difficult, I don't think there are shells that support multithreading directly, but of course you could start external programs simultaneously in several ways. But I'm not even sure if that's what you want, so the unclarity remains in that, too.

Comment: You need to get someone to explain this university coursework to you.  You do not understand it well enough yourself to be able to explain it coherently to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shell can call a program but it cannot make a program multi-threaded (unless the program supports that and can be called with e.g. arguments which control this behaviour).

A shell can call a program several times (with different arguments or environment in the background), though. Whether this is possible and makes sense depends on how the program works.